# Como formatar código a seguir a uma lista?

Tags: suporte, formatação

Tenho verificado que a formatação de código (<kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>) não fica bem feita quando o código está a seguir a uma lista.

A solução que eu tenho utilizado é introduzir uma linha com texto entre a lista e o código.
Foi o que fiz nesta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38801/2541).

Pouco tempo depois ela foi novamente editada(Bigown) apresentado o código corretamente formatado sem recurso áquela linha.
Foi ver a edição mas não consegui perceber como isso foi feito.

Comment: Acho que isto pode ser marcado como duplicata de [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1084). Está lá nas seções **Código** e **Listas**. Mas resumindo: ou usa-se 8 espaços de tabulação (e o código fica alinhado com a lista) ou coloca-se um separador invisível `<!-- br -->`.

Comment: Tem razão, eu até já tinha visto essa pergunta, não li a resposta com a devida atenção.